# jquery filter not working when context element provided

Tags: jquery

[Very simple JSFiddle demonstrates the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/PguVw/1/) (you'll need to view a debug console since `console.log` is used to demonstrate the problem). The 2nd console.log statement is empty. However the code works if I remove`el` from the following line:

`var items = $('li[data-level="2"]', el);`

so that it becomes:

`var items = $('li[data-level="2"]');`

then the code works. Can anyone explain why this is? Don't know why the line declaring `el` would be missing, it's showing for me in JSFiddle, but here's all the code in the JavaScript panel:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var el = $('ul');
    var items = $('li[data-level="2"]', el);
    console.log(items);
    var visible = items.filter(':visible');
    console.log(visible);
});
```

Comment: what was `el` before you removed it?

Comment: So you need to use `el` or you don't need to use `el`? I'm confused what the problem is.

Comment: I'm getting the same results with or without the context. The second log spits out the visible elements, which there aren't any because you've hidden them all with your CSS.

Comment: Your demo works fine and returns as expected. With `el` or without `el` it returns the same.

Comment: **The 2nd console.log statement is empty**, Yes it should be empty as you are filtering `:visible` and none of them are visible as `display:none` is set in CSS. May be you are looking for `:hidden` to get the hidden `li`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have all of the `li` elements set to `display:none`, which is why `el.filter(':visible')` returns an empty collection. I'm not sure I see the *problem* here.

jQuery's `$.filter` method will return all of the items in the collection that **match** the selector passed into the filter. So if we were to select all list items, and strong items:

```
$("li, strong");
```

And then filter it so that we only have list items:

```
$("li, strong").filter("li");
```

Our result would only be list items. In your case, you have created an unordered list, replete with three hidden list items. You have selected all of these, and then attempted to filter them to only see those that are `:visible`, but since you hid them all with `display:none` in your CSS, the resulting collection will be empty.

jQuery is worked as expected.

Comment: Ugh, sorry, having a hell of a time recreating my problem. But finally managed it.  The problem I was experiencing was down to calling trigger() on a model, for example: `this.model.trigger('change:title');`, and then filtering by visibility. I didn't realise `trigger` was asynchronous, so the code that did the filtering got run before the method which updated the visibility!